# What happens in the last step of the proof of the definite integral?

Tags: calculus

I have trouble in understanding the proof of definite integrals. Can someone explain the last step in this picture?
user image

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8wbFl.png)

The text is Danish. In English the first two lines says:

1. Target: A = ....
2. We know: A(x) is an integral of f(x)

Comment: Hello @Alexander Nielsen, welcome to MSE. [Here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question) is some information on how to ask a good question. May I suggest you type the question itself instead of adding a picture. In [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) you find a tutorial on MathJax, which is used to typset mathematical formulas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just substituting the value of the integration constant $c$ in the last step.

In the first step when we obtain

$$A(a) = 0 = F(a) +c$$

$$\implies c = -F(a)$$

And now when we calculate $A(b)$ as

$$A(b) = F(b) + c$$

We plug in the value of $c = -F(a)$ obtained in the first step.

Comment: Ah, I see, thank you!

Comment: Yes, of course!